# Can't get a ws WebSocket server to run on Vite dev server. WS_ERR_INVALID_CLOSE_CODE

Tags: node.js, websocket, vite, sveltekit, ws

I'm trying to get a WebSocket server to run on top of Vite's built-in dev server. I'm grabbing the `httpServer` instance directly from Vite and asking `ws` to listen on it, and it gives a fatal error which I can't find mentioned anywhere on the web.

I tried manually listening for `"upgrade"` events on Vite's `httpServer` and calling `ws.Server.handleUpgrade()` myself, but that gives me the same exact error. If I run all the code and simply leave off the call to `handleUpgrade()` then it will stop giving any errors. The error definitely seems to come from `handleUpgrade()`, I just have no clue what the error means or how to fix it.

It should be noted that I'm using SvelteKit and TypeScript in this project. This is my `vite.config.ts` file:

```
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";

const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        {
            name: "webSocketServer",
            configureServer: (viteDevServer: any) => {
                const webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer({
                    server: viteDevServer.httpServer
                });
            }
        }
    ]
};

export default config;
```

This is the error I get when running the `npm run dev` command:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 16001
    at Receiver.controlMessage (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:566:18)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:442:42)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:158:22)
    at Receiver._write (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:84:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Socket.socketOnData (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1274:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at Receiver.receiverOnError (C:\Users\MSJim\Documents\programming-data\visual-studio-code\frontends\sveltekit-websockets-chat\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1160:13)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'WS_ERR_INVALID_CLOSE_CODE',
  [Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
}
```

Where it reads `invalid status code 16001`, the `16001` seems to change every time I run it. I have gotten `39338`, `38329`, and `29320` when running it 3 additional times.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did not. I'm sorry. I ended up just running a completely separate WebSocket server. It's not ideal, but at least it's straightforward.